# Convert a decimal to a fraction

Tags: code-golf, rational-numbers

Write a program that converts a decimal to a mixed, simplified fraction.

Sample input:

```
5.2
```

Sample output:

```
5 + (1/5)
```

The code with the shortest length in bytes wins.

Comment: Easy: `1.2345 = 12345/10000`. You give me the precision & I'll give you the fraction!

Comment: Do you mean simplified fractions?

Comment: i meant mixed fractions

Comment: basically: find how many spaces the decimal goes beyond the decimal point (e.g. 2.357 is 3 digits after decimal), then turn it into improper, unsimplified: 2357/1000 and then, have a list of primes, starting at lowest, try to divide both numbers by it without remainder, then try it on that until at least one of the numbers is a prime and the other is not divisible by that number, and you're done

Comment: @CrowdStar: Does the fractional part need to be simplified?

Comment: Yep, it has to be. @Gelatin

Comment: 5.2 != 5+1/2...

Comment: @Markasoftware: That won't necessarily work (the factor might not be prime) and it could take a long time. The best way (AFAIK) is to find the gcd of both (using the Euclidean algorithm) and divide through.

Comment: Is there a convention for negative mixed fractions? What about proper fractions?: 0+3/7 or simply 3/7 ?

Comment: @Gelatin I'm pretty sure all whole numbers which are greater than 1 and are not prime have at least one factor that is prime.

Comment: @Markasoftware: I guess it would work if you did it more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Ruby, 43

```
y=gets.to_r;puts"#{y.to_i} + (#{y-y.to_i})"
```

Pretty straightforward.

Comment: Interesting solution. I'm honestly surprised you can make such short program with correct output format.

Comment: Ruby has a lot of Lispy features and the Rational class is probably one of the lesser-known ones. However, if the input is a float you're liable to get something like "2 + (1499999999999999/5000000000000000)"

Answer (score 2):

### python 3, 84

```
from fractions import*
a,b=input().split(".")
print("%s + (%s)"%(a,Fraction("."+b)))
```

Comment: Doesn't return the output in correct format. `+` should be returned (but otherwise, it's close to expected format).

Comment: @GlitchMr Edited the format.

Comment: Also, there are parens. Dunno why, but the OP put them.

Comment: @GlitchMr Added those creepy parens. Now the code size raised to 84 :-(

Comment: 81 bytes using f-string, [code](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3A9OK8nMV0ooSk0sy8_OKFTJzC_KLSrS4EnWSbDPzCkpLNDT1igtyMks0lPSUNLkKijLzSjTSlKoTaxW0FTSq3aAaNdT11LWTNGs1lTQhBkPNX7DYVM8UwgQA)

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript, 40

```
'.'/~'+'\.~.@,10\?.@{.@\%.}do;:d/\d/'/'@
```

Requires no line terminator in the input. Can probably be golfed further.

Answer (score 1):

### Golf-Basic 84, 32 characters

Executed from a TI-84 calculator

```
i`A:floor(A)→B:A-B→A:d`Bd`A►Frac
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 73

No cigar this time. `Numerator`, `Denominator` and `Rationalize` are big words.

```
f@x_:=(Row@{⌊#⌋,"+",Numerator@#~Mod~(d=Denominator@#)/d})&[Rationalize@x]
```

Example

```
f[23.872]
```

[image: mixed]

Answer (score 1):

### [GTB](http://timtechsoftware.com/gtb), 28

```
`A:floor(A)→B:A-B→A~B~A►Frac
```

Comment: The source code for your compiler cannot be run since iX2Web is not available. The link in your site is bad as well.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6 (53 bytes)

Does the output in right, expected format. Would be way shorter if output in invalid format would be allowed. This gets a number, converts it to rational. `nude` method returns denominator and numerator (there are separate `denominator` and `numerator` methods, but they are crazily long.

`[]` is a reduce operator which takes operator between square brackets, and in this case, I use it to shorten the code (so I wouldn't have to specify both array elements, because they are already in correct order (but if they wouldn't, there are `R` operators (like `R/`, `R%`, `Rdiv`, and `Rmod`) that reverse the order of arguments for operator)). `{}` in double quotes puts the result of code in string (like `#{}` in Ruby).

`my \` is declaration of sigilless variable. In this case it doesn't save characters, but it doesn't waste them either, so why not use it. I could have used `my@`, and it would use identical number of characters.

```
my \n=get.Rat.nude;say "{[div] n} + ({[%] n}/{n[1]})"
```

Sample output (just to show the correct format):

```
~ $ perl6 -e 'my \n=get.Rat.nude;say "{[div] n} + ({[%] n}/{n[1]})"'
42.42
42 + (21/50)
```

If negative number support is needed, this would work (2 bytes more).

```
~ $ perl6 -e 'my \n=get.Rat.nude;say "{[div] n} + ({[mod] n}/{n[1]})"'
-42.42
-42 + (-21/50)
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, several lines

How about the way they tought us at grammar school?

```
f=function(s){
  gcd=function(a,b)if(!b)a else gcd(b,a%%b)
  a=strsplit(s,'\\.')[[1]]
  p=10^nchar(a[2])
  x=strtoi(a[2])
  d=gcd(x,p);
  cat(a[1]," + (",x/d,"/",p/d,")",sep="");
}
```

Vaguely: works for positive decimals with finite decimal fraction.

```
> f("23.872")
23 + (109/125)
```

Input must be a string matching "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell

Isn't pretty, but whatever

```
import Data.Ratio
main=let r '%'='/';r c=c in interact$(\(x,y)->show x++" + "++map r(show$approxRational y 1e-9)).properFraction.read
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
I₌I-ƒJ`% + (%/%)`$%
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=I%E2%82%8CI-%C6%92J%60%25%20%2B%20%28%25%2F%25%29%60%24%25&inputs=420.240&header=&footer=)

It's convoluted because of the handling of the output format

### Explained (old)

```
:I₌₴-ƒ\/j`...`$%,
:I                # int(input)
  ₌₴-             # print(top, end=""), input - int(input) [gets the fractional part] 
     ƒ            # Turn the decimal into a simplified fraction
      \/j         # Join that on "/"
         `...`    # The string " + (%)" -> this will be used for formatting the output
              $%, # perform string formatting and output the fraction part
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 34 bytes

```
phAcQ\.s[" + ("/sHKisHJ*TlH\//JK\)
```

Not that proud of this but that output format was getting to my head

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vyDDMTkwRq84WklBW0FDSb/Ywzuz2MNLKyTHI0Zf38s7RvP/fyVDPSOlf/kFJZn5ecX/dVMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 34 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.25 bytes

```
1ḋ\+j
```

Does divmod with 1 and then joins on `+`. Outputs `a+b/c`.

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiMeG4i1xcK2oiLCIiLCIyLjcxIl0=)

### If the IO format was a bit looser

#### 2 bytes

```
1ḋ
```

Does divmod with 1. Outputs `⟨ a | b/c ⟩`

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCIx4biLIiwiIiwiMi43MSJd)

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 134 bytes

```rkt
((λ(f[d(denominator f)][n(numerator f)])(printf"~a + (~a)"(quotient n d)(rationalize(/(modulo n d)d)(/ 1 d))))(inexact->exact(read)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpBCsIwFESv8qmbCaK1iAs3XqS4@DS/Ekx/NCQgLnox7@CVYqw4m5k3M5GHq6Sy8qwXij8A3i@MvYUVDZNTTiHSaM69QvMk8c8Gt@g0jc3MtCbMbBrcc0hONJGSNahXF5S9ewpaTMFmH5albi11NVTBqTx4SJvTYojC376U3fbY7Q8f)

---

### Explanation

Racket natively supports fractions. Fractions are referred to as "exact number" as the values of fraction aren't affected by IEEE floating-point conversion.

Racket also has support for `float`s, similar to what is present in other languages. These floats are called inexact numbers because their accuracy is limited to what can be stored in a certain number of bytes (IEEE standards).

> [Read more about Racket Numbers.](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/numbers.html)

Since the user inputs a float with a decimal point, we need to convert the number into a fraction using `inexact->exact`. Once our input is converted, we can extract the denominator and the numerator of the fraction.

```rkt
((λ (frac [den (denominator frac)] [num (numerator frac)])
   ...)
 (inexact->exact (read)))
```

After that, We create a format string that will printed with the following format parameters:

1. The whole part of the fraction.

   1. Calculated by dividing the numerator `num` by the denominator `den`.
2. A simplified version of the remaining fraction.

   1. Modulo the numerator `num` by the denominator `den`.
   2. Create a new fraction with the previous step as the numerator and the denominator as `den`.
   3. Rationalize the new fraction with a tolerance of \$\frac{1}{\text{den}}\$.

```rkt
((λ (frac [den (denominator frac)] [num (numerator frac)])
   (printf "~a + (~a)"
           (quotient n d)
           (rationalize (/ (modulo n d) d)
                        (/ 1 d))))
 (inexact->exact (read)))
```

---

*Have a great week further!*