# Convert a fraction to a repeated decimal

Tags: code-golf, rational-numbers

Almost the polar opposite if [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17907/convert-a-repeated-decimal-to-a-fraction) challenge, and I suspect it will be slightly easier.

Your task is to take two integers in the format `a/b` (Forming a rational number) then output the number in decimal exactly.

For example, if you were to input `1/3`, it would output:

```
0.33333333333333333
```

And would keep on printing 3s until the end of time, with an optional leading 0. (You could also print *one* character per line if and *only if* your language does not allow printing on the same line.)

The behaviour for `x/0` will be undefined. For a number that looks like it doesn't repeat (Like, say `5/4`) it actually does repeat. Either of the following two forms would be acceptable for `5/4`:

```
1.25000000000000000
1.24999999999999999
```

(The same with whole numbers, `1.9999999` or `2.000000`)

The fraction may not be in its simplest form, and `a` or `b` may be negative (Note `-a/b = -(a/b)`, `-a/-b = a/b`, `a/-b = -a/b`, and `-.6249999` is invalid, but `-0.6249999` is acceptable, but you still can use.

Comment: Can we use Unix `bc`, or is that cheating?

Comment: Before I keep golfing my answer: Can `a` and/or `b` be negative?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, but either `a` or `b` (or both) can be negative)

Comment: @DavidRTribble I think that's a standard loophole, so no.

Comment: Does your latest edit say that leading zeroes are okay with positive numbers, but not negative ones? If so, what's the reason for that?

Comment: @Geobits No it says the opposite (`.0`, `0.0`, `-0.0` are all OK, but `-.0` isn't as it looks weird.)

Comment: Right, that's what I meant, said it backward. So the reason is "it looks weird"? Okay...

Comment: Your last edit make some answer invalid (mine, above all). That should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CJam, <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
l'/%:i2*~*0<'-*o:Dmd\zo'.{oA*Dmd\z1}g
```

#### How it works

```
l     e# Read line from STDIN.            STACK '17/-13'
'/%   e# Split at '/'.                    STACK ['17' '-13']
:i    e# Cast each element to int.        STACK [17 -13]
2*~   e# Duplicate and dump the array.    STACK 17 -13 17 -13
*     e# Multiply.                        STACK 17 -13 -221
0<    e# Compare with zero.               STACK 17 -13 1
'-*o  e# Print '-' that many times.       STACK 17 -13
:D    e# Save the topmost integer in D.   STACK 17 -13
md    e# Perform modular division.        STACK -1 4
\z    e# Swap and take absolute value.    STACK 4 1
o'.   e# Print and push '.'.              STACK 4 '.'
{     e# do:
  o   e#   Print.                         STACK 4
  A*  e#   Multiply by 10.                STACK 40
  Dmd e#   Divide modulo D.               STACK -3 1
  \z  e#   Swap and take absolute value.  STACK 1 3
  o   e#   Print.                         STACK 1
1}g   e# while(1)
```

Comment: Since you use double division isn't this totally broken for big numbers?

Comment: @orlp: Totally. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

## C, 108 <s>79</s>

**Edit** Modified to work with negative numbers.

Input from stdin. Old K&R style.

```c
main(a,b){char*s="-%d.";scanf("%d/%d",&a,&b);for(a*b<0?(a<0?a=-a:(b=-b)):++s;printf(s,a/b);s="%d")a=a%b*10;}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>83</s> <s>69</s> <s>102</s> <s>91</s> 89 bytes

```rb
->s{a,b=s.scan(/\d+/).map &:to_i
eval(s+?r)<0&&$><<?-
$><<a/b<<?.
loop{a=a%b*10
$><<a/b}}
```

Simple implementation of manual integer division based on the computer's integer division.

Thanks to @blutorange for the help in golfing.

Edit: Fixed the solution to include negative numbers.

Comment: By making use of some shortcuts in ruby, you can bring this down to 66 bytes: `->s{a,b=s.split(?/).map &:to_i;$><<a/b<<?.;loop{a=a%b*10;$><<a/b}}` I just love this about ruby.

Comment: Wow, I just learned many things, thank you! I didn't remember about `?/` to denote characters, nor did I know about `$><<` to print or the `loop` keyword. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome, I didn't know about many of these tricks either until somebody pointed it out. `$>` is short for `$stdout`, and `<<` is an operator. You can save one more byte in the second line by changing it to `c*d<0&&$><<?-`; a few bytes by combining the 3rd/4th line to `$><<a/b<<?.`, and one more by removing the space after `<<` in the last line. And here's an idea to bring it down to 91 bytes: `->s{a,b=s.scan(/\d+/).map &:to_i;1==s.count(?-)&&$><<?-;$><<a/b<<?.;loop{a=a%b*10;$><<a/b}}` (ruby 2.2.0)

Comment: The syntax for `$><<a/b` didn't work correctly, that's why I put the space there. The rest seems good, thank you very much!

Comment: That's interesting, perhaps the ruby version you're using doesn't like it without spaces? It works fine for me and [at ideone](http://ideone.com/oNl43K). Funny enough, it breaks the syntax highlighting of my code editor, though...

Comment: Oh, maybe it works and I just assumed it didn't because of the syntax highlighting in vim... edit: after trying it, it works, it was the syntax highlighting that led me to believe it wouldn't

Comment: If you're still interested, there's also [a rational literal](http://ruby.about.com/od/Whats-New-in-Ruby-210/fl/Whats-new-in-Ruby-210-Numerics.htm) (`Rational(2,3) == 2/3r`) since ruby 2.1 (that I learned about 10 mins ago) that can be used to shorten the second line: `eval(s+?r)<0&&$><<?-`

Comment: Thanks a lot! wow, ruby is really a complete language in many ways... And you are a true source of information!

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>177</s> <s>176</s> 170

```
s->{try{int x=new Integer(s.split("/")[0]),y=new Integer(s.split("/")[1]),z=1;for(;;x=x%y*10,Thread.sleep(999))System.out.print(x/y+(z-->0?".":""));}catch(Exception e){}}
```

The algorithm is straightforward; the tricky part was getting the printing to work. In the end, I had the computer sleep for a second between each step so it could print.

### Expanded, runnable version

```
public class RepeatedDecimal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.function.Consumer<String> f = s -> {
                try {
                    int x = new Integer(s.split("/")[0]),
                        y = new Integer(s.split("/")[1]),
                        z = 1;
                    for (;; x = x % y * 10, Thread.sleep(999)) {
                        System.out.print(x / y + (z-- > 0 ? "." : ""));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) { }
                };

        f.accept("5/7");
    }
}
```

Comment: While the output does have a flushing problem, I was able to get it to show output by sleeping for 9ms which would shave two bytes.

Comment: @Snowman It probably depends on the hardware or OS; my computer won't work with less than 250ms or so.

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>103</s> <s>137</s> <s>109</s> 103

Bit happier with this now.  Using scan with a separator save a lot of bytes.  May still have some room for improvement.
Replaced `<-` with `=`.  Haven't always had the best of luck with this, but it worked this time.

```R
cat(if(prod(i=scan(sep='/'))<0)'-',(n=(i=abs(i))[1])%/%(d=i[2]),'.',sep='');repeat cat((n=n%%d*10)%/%d)
```

Test runs

```R
> cat(if(prod(i=scan(sep='/'))<0)'-',(n=(i=abs(i))[1])%/%(d=i[2]),'.',sep='');repeat cat((n=n%%d*10)%/%d)
1: -1/3
3: 
Read 2 items
-0.33333333333333333333...
> cat(if(prod(i=scan(sep='/'))<0)'-',(n=(i=abs(i))[1])%/%(d=i[2]),'.',sep='');repeat cat((n=n%%d*10)%/%d)
1: -5/-4
3: 
Read 2 items
1.250000000000000000000...
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>107</s> 115 bytes

```
a,b=map(int,input().split("/"))
print(("%.1f"%(a/b))[:-1],end="")
b=abs(b)
while 1:a=abs(a)%b*10;print(a//b,end="")
```

Pretty straightforward:

- Input the numerator and denominator
- Output the the quotient with 1 digit after the decimal point, then take off the last digit (e.g. `-1/3` -> `-0.`)
- Take absolute values*
- Loop:

  - Numerator is remainder after dividing out denominator
  - Multiply numerator by 10
  - Output integer quotient as next digit

* (Though the calculation for `a` was moved inside the loop to save a few bytes.)

**Edit:** Fixed bug with negative fractions > -1.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7, 209 bytes

```
from sys import*;m,o=1,lambda x:stdout.write(str(x));a,b=[int(x)for x in argv[1].split('/')]
o(str(a*b)[0]);a,b=abs(a),abs(b);o('0'*(b>a))
while 1:
 while not((m*a)/b):o('0.'[m==1]);m*=10
 o((m*a)/b);a=(m*a)%b
```

### edit:

Now outputs all characters on the same line, as asked.

### edit2:

Now reads the fraction from commandline argument, as requested :)

Comment: A few tips: 1) Using `map` instead of the list comprehension saves quite a bit; 2) don't need the parentheses around `m*a` in any of its locations, as `*`, `%`, and `/` are all the same precedence and left-associative; 3) the 0-or-dot logic on line 3 can be simplified to `"0."[m==1]`, since you're just printing it anyway; 4) probably will save chars to merely set `o=stdout.write` and [convert numeric arguments to string with backticks](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55/16766) as needed.

Comment: Also, the code doesn't appear to work with negatives: `1/-3` gives `-1.666666666` instead of `-0.333333333`.